# Want to show only the columns of data that relate to a maximum value in column for each unique row

Tags: sql

I have the following data table from OverdueLetterHistory. Listing multiple debtor letters sent to each debtor.

```
SELECT
    DebtorID, 
    LetterSeq,
    LetterDate,
    Comment 
FROM
    DebtorOverdueLetterHistory
```

The below returns the maximum LetterSeq per debtor, but I cannot also add the LetterDate and Comment with getting errors.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DebtorID,
    MAX (LetterSeq) AS 'MaxLetterSeq'
FROM
    DebtorOverdueLetterHistory
GROUP BY
    DebtorID
```

How can I show the `LetterDate` and `Comment` for only the maximum `LetterSeq` for each unique debtor? I only want to see the details of the last letter sent to each debtor.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DebtorOverdueLetterHistory.DebtorID,
    MAX(DebtorOverdueLetterHistory.LetterSeq) AS 'MaxLetterSeq'
FROM
    DebtorOverdueLetterHistory
GROUP BY
    DebtorID
```

Comment: You can use row_number() or self join for this purpose. Also, distinct is not required in your current query, you are already getting distinct values by using group by.

Comment: You forgot to disclose your RDBMS and version.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get each DebtorID's most recent row:

```
SELECT DebtorID, 
       LetterSeq,
       LetterDate,
       Comment
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DebtorID, 
        LetterSeq,
        LetterDate,
        Comment,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTTION BY DebtorID ORDER BY LetterDate DESC) rowno
    FROM
        DebtorOverdueLetterHistory
) dt
WHERE rowno = 1
```

Will work on most modern dbms:s.

Alternatively, use `NOT EXISTS` - which is core ISO SQL - i.e. expected to run on any dbms:

```
SELECT
    DebtorID, 
    LetterSeq,
    LetterDate,
    Comment
FROM
    DebtorOverdueLetterHistory d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        DebtorOverdueLetterHistory d2
    WHERE d2.DebtorID = d1.DebtorID
      AND d2.LetterDate > d1.LetterDate)
```